# Multilingual Section Name Does Not Work in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

Please see this MWE given below where we are using two
languages. English is the main language, and [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language)
is the second language.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi}

\begin{document}

English text.

% Languages switching works fine in normal text.
\begin{bengali}
   বাংলা লেখা
\end{bengali}

% Languages switching fails in section name.
\section{English text \begin{bengali}বাংলা লেখা\end{bengali}}

% Even protecting does not work
\protect{\section{English text \begin{bengali}বাংলা লেখা\end{bengali}}}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, we get an error message:

> ```
> ! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> l.22 ...বাংলা লেখা\end{bengali}}
> ```

How do we tackle this problem?

Comment: What about `\section{English text \textbengali{বাংলা লেখা}}`? I don't think using environments is that good an idea here.

Comment: @moewe Oh, dear! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks a lot.